# Custom container unnecessarily creating new elements instances when space is reserved

Tags: c++, constructor, containers, allocation

For my own education, I am trying to learn how to implement efficient custom containers in C++. I have now a basic working version of a my custom vector type. However, for some reason, when the vector has to be expanded to fit more elements (in which case a call to its inner 'reserve' function is made), it creates extra copies of elements.

To help explaining what I mean, I show below a minimum reproducible example. Let a minimum version of `CustomVector` class look like the following:

```
template<class T>
class CustomVector
{
private:
    size_t m_size = 0;
    size_t m_capacity = 1;
    T *m_data = nullptr;

public:
CustomVector()
{
}

CustomVector(const size_t new_capacity)
{
    m_capacity = new_capacity;
    m_size = 0;
    m_data = new T[m_capacity]();
}

~CustomVector()
{
    if (m_data != nullptr)
        delete[] m_data;
}

void reserve(size_t new_capacity)
{
    if (m_data == nullptr)
    {
        m_capacity = new_capacity;
        m_size = 0;
        m_data = new T[m_capacity]();
    }
    else if (new_capacity > m_capacity)
    {
        T* new_data = new T[new_capacity]();
        memmove(new_data, m_data, (m_size) * sizeof(T));
        delete[] m_data;
        m_capacity = new_capacity;
        m_data = new_data;
    }
}

void push_back(const T & value)
{
    if (m_data == nullptr)
    {
        m_capacity = 1;
        m_size = 0;
        m_data = new T[m_capacity]();
        m_data[0] = value;
    }
    else if (m_size + 1 >= m_capacity)
    {
        reserve(m_capacity*2);
    }
    else
    {
        m_data[m_size-1] = value;
        m_size++;
    }
}
```

};

Now, to facilitate seeing the problem, I also create a class called `Object`. Each new instance of such class that is created automatically receives an unique id number:

```
class Object
{
private:
    static int idCounter;
public:
    int id;
    Object()
    {
        id = idCounter;
        idCounter++;
    }
};
int Object::idCounter = 0;
```

Lastly, here is how the `main` function of this example looks like:

```
int main()
{
    CustomVector<Object> objects; //comment this line...
    //std::vector<Object> objects; //...and uncomment this to try with std::vector
Object x;
printf("%d\n", x.id);
objects.push_back(x);

Object y;
printf("%d\n", y.id);
objects.push_back(y);

Object z;
printf("%d ", z.id);

system("Pause");
return 0;
```

}

The output, using my `CustomVector` as the container, is:

> 0 2 5

While the output using a `std::vector` as the container is:

> 0 1 2

The desirable behavior for me is exactly that of `std::vector`, that is, pushing back instances of classes should create full new temporary instances of such class.

Could someone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would my question be downvoted? I would like to read so I can improve it. I clearly show my effort, I brought a reproducible example and I have a clear question.

Comment: On an unrelated note, it's okay and valid to use null-pointers when using `delete` or `delete[]`. It just does nothing then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely this line in the `push_back` function:

```
m_data = new T[m_capacity]();
```

This will cause the creation of `m_capacity` number of `T` objects, and therefore `m_capacity` calls to the `T` constructor. This is bad if the `T` constructor is expensive (not to mention some beginners do input and other things in the constructor).

What `std::vector` most likely does is keeping a buffer of *bytes*, and then when pushing back it does *placement new* to construct an object in place in some position in the buffer.